# Blinking LED - start and stop

Tags: gpio, python, led

This is my first post here so HELLO and sorry if I'm posting in the wrong place.

Do you know a simple bit of Python that will set a LED blinking indefinitely until it's told to stop?
Control will be carried out by another program so that the command ctrl + C is not useful.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi There and welcome to Raspberry Stack Exchange. Please try and ask specific questions that relate to the Pi. On this site you will find questions about WiringPi. Have you tired that? Try and search for that and if you run into another problem, please return and ask a specific question about it and what you have tried. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiringpi

Comment: How will the Python script be told to stop?

Comment: As @joan says, what tells it to stop?  Recognising CTRL-C is a good thing to do - it means handling - at least on \*nix systems - the reception of `SIGTERM` signals. Although that key-combo is one way to send that signal to a program *in the foreground* other ways also exist; e.g. with a plain `kill `<pid> sent by you as owner of that program running in the background or by the system at shutdown. In the latter case each running program gets a `SIGTERM` to "please close down cleanly NOW" - before it gets a `SIGKILL` that terminates it with **extreme prejudice** if it ignores the first request!

Comment: But how to do that by giving the command in cron stop and start the process?